# Javascript method with XMLHttpRequest returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following method that should return either true or false:

```
theMethod() {
    const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open("GET", 'http://someurl.com', true);
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    };
}
```

In both cases it's returning 'undefined'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Only the anonymous function is returning true/false, theMethod is not returning anything. And the function itself won't execute whenever you call theMethod. True would have to be returned in future. Plus I think `onreadystatechange` is assigned before `send()`. You should pass two functions to the method and call them instead of returning true or false. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thisMethod` will always return `undefined`, because it has no `return` statement in it. All it does is make an Ajax request, which of course is asynchronous - it will only complete *after* `thisMethod` has returned. (Or hasn't, as the case is here.)

You attached a callback function to that Ajax call - as is normal, indeed required in order to be able to do anything with the results. *That* function is the one which returns either `true` or `false` to indicate whether the Ajax succeeded or not. But `thisMethod` itself doesn't return anything.

Note that your callback which just returns a value won't actually have any observable effect - because you are not doing anything with the return value. Typically you don't with a callback like this, you just *do something* with the response (typically render it on the page somewhere, or log it to the console).